# Plot freezing because of fast input stream to a GNU Radio block

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, gnuradio

I have implemented a `sync block` which plots inside its `work` function using the `input_items` values. Now the problem is that the plotting mechanism isn't fast enough for the input stream ( the value of `input_items` keeps on changing ).

I have tried to simplify the code as much as possible and added comments. Here it is:

```
....
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
temp = ''
class xyz(gr.sync_block):
    def __init__(self,parent,title,order):
        a = []
        self.count = 1
        gr.sync_block.__init__(self,
                name="xyz",
                in_sig=[numpy.float32,numpy.float32],
                out_sig=None)
        self.win = xyzPlot(parent) #I have a Top Block(wxFrame). I am just making it the parent of xyzPlot(wxPanel) here.

    def work(self, input_items, output_items):
        global temp
        if (self.count == 1):
            temp = input_items+list()
        bool = not(np.allclose(temp,input_items))#bool will be true if the value of `input_items` changes. 
        .......
        #the code that evaluates z1,z2 depending on the value of input_items    
        .......
        if ( bool or self.count == 1 ):
        #If bool is true or it is the first time then I am calling plot() which plots the graph. 
            self.win.plot(tf(self.z1,self.z3),None,True,True,True,True)
        self.count = 0
        temp = input_items+list()
        return len(input_items[0])

class xyzPlot(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, dB=None, Hz=None, deg=None):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self , parent , -1 ,size=(600,475))
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

    def plot(self, syslist, omega=None, dB=None, Hz=None, deg=None, Plot=True, *args , **kwargs):
        self.axes.clear() #I clear the graph here so that new values can be plotted.
        .....
        self.axes.semilogx(omega,mag,*args,**kwargs)
        self.canvas = FigCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)
        self.canvas.draw()
```

As you can see I am working with wxPython but the panel freezes whenever I change the value of `input_items` too fast ( It works fine if I change it slowly ). Any recommendations? I am new to this.

Comment: Don't clear the axes and rebuild the artist. Create it once, and keep a reference to it. Then you can use `set_data` to only change the data points. Same holds for the canvas. Only create it once, then calling `draw`  should be enough to update the figure.

Comment: @hitzg: True, but the problem seems to be that he's asynchronously and at high rates plotting things in a thread that's not the GUI thread. I think you might be better used to matplotlib/wx integration, so I'd love to see your comment under my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31068633/4433386).

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ Not really. My comment is merely a recommendation on how to speed up the update of a plot.

Comment: @hitzg: I understood the change with respect to the canvas. How to use `set_data` in his case as he is using `semilogx`?

Comment: `semilogx` works exactly as `plot`. It returns a list of artists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cite [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703138/how-exactly-is-hier-block-s-behaviour-different-then-that-of-a-sync-block-in-gn) I gave:

> This will quickly also get a multithreading problem. To be clear: What
>   you're trying to do (call a plotting function from a block thread) is
>   problematic and usually won't work.

The problem is that you're working in a complex multithreading environment:

- each GNU Radio block works in its own thread
- The WX Gui main loop runs continously to update the screen.

What you're doing here is, from a GNU Radio block thread, change what is shown in the window. That is a bad thing, because it changes things that are in the context of the WX Gui thread. This *can* work, if these changes don't conflict, and if the WX Gui thread doesn't access this kind of data while you're changing it (at some point, it has to access it -- otherwise, noone will update your window).

This is a problem common to all kind of updated GUIs, not only to GNU Radio!

Whether or not that happens is a mere case of probability: With a slowly updated display, your probability of conflict is low, but when you update often, it approaches 1.

The existing visualizations are written in C++ and take very great care to do things the right way  -- which is, letting your Gui toolkit (WX in your case, though I explicitely recommend, and have recommended, to move away from that) know that things need to be updated, and then offering WX a function to update the display in its own thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are there any tutorials available on how to feed an existing visualizer with samples? Could you please guide me to them or to files which implement a similar thing so I could go through the code?

Comment: @PuRaK: the guided tutorials are your friend. You just stream in samples. The source code is openly available, http://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio . Look into the gr-qtgui/lib (or if you really want to do that, don't do that, WX is dead, gr-wxgui) folder.