# How to feed an existing visualizer with values from a sync_block in GNU Radio?

Tags: multithreading, matplotlib, wxpython, gnuradio

This is a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068361/plot-freezing-because-of-fast-input-stream-to-a-gnu-radio-block) question. I understand that calling a plotting function from a block thread is problematic because it might conflict with the WX Gui thread.

Can anyone show me a very simple code snippet which plots the value of `input_items` using an *existing visualizer* instead of plotting it inside the block thread?

Here is an outline of the GNU Radio sync_block which receives the values to be plotted in `input_items` :

```
import numpy
from gnuradio import gr

class xyz(gr.sync_block):
    def __init__(self, multiple):
        gr.sync_block.__init__(self,
            name="xyz",
            in_sig=[<+numpy.float+>],
            out_sig=[<+numpy.float+>])

    def work(self, input_items, output_items):
        in0 = input_items[0]
        out = output_items[0]
        .....
        # How to pass the value of input_items to an existing visualizer which plots a graph based on these values on the GUI
        .....
        out[:] = in0
        return len(output_items[0])
```

Also which existing plot block(*in gnuradio/gr-wxgui*) is suggested to be used as a reference for this?